# menu will not un-collapse when click on button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am really a newbie in bootstrap 3.

I have made this menu that will collapse when screen is resized, but nothing happend when I click on the button.

```
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar-highlight btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                                NAVIGATION <span class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></span>
                            </button>

                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills ddmenu">
                                    <li class="dropdown active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="page.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Page <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="full.html">Full Page</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="2-column.html">Two Column</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="3-column.html">Three Column</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="../documentation/index.html">Documentation</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown Item &nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>

                    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher.
You can use version 1.12.0, which is the last one of the 1.X branch at the moment, and it should work :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap should have notified you about this in your browser's javascript console directly, you should enable it as soon as you develop with projects that deal with JavaScript.

Comment: When I click on the button it will go to this navbar-collapse collapsing it has to go to navbar-collapse in collapse instead

Comment: I have tried your code and replaced jQuery's version with the one I mentioned and it's working : when the screen is resized I see a navigation button and when I click on it the menu unfolds. Do you have any errors output in the console ?

Comment: I have take a collapse menu from bootstrap 2 and trying to convert it to bootstrap 3